# How to config flask app.logger from a configure file?

Tags: python, logging, flask

Is there any way to config flask app.logger from a configure file, like:

```
logging.config.fileConfig('/path/to/logging.cfg')
```

or

```
logging.config.dictConfig(config_dict)
```

So i can use `app.logger.info('some message')` to log both in develop and product mode.

Comment: Since flask uses the standard `logging` module, they should hook right up. whathaveyoutried.com ?

Comment: i tried `logging.config.dictConfig`, but it not works.

Comment: You need to post more detail about what you've tried - otherwise it's hard to know what the problem might be.

Comment: i use [logging.cfg](https://github.com/kingheaven/ScriptFan.com/blob/5f0ee791da9d77e67ab8326c964e7c5de5aa89e3/website/scriptfan/logging.cfg.sample) and load the cfg file like [this](https://github.com/kingheaven/ScriptFan.com/blob/5f0ee791da9d77e67ab8326c964e7c5de5aa89e3/website/scriptfan/__init__.py#L19) but when I use app.logger.info('...') to log, my configuration not works, still got flask's DebugLogger settings.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `app.logger` first and then `logging.config.dictConfig(config_dict)`. The logger name should be the same in config_dict and in app.logger_name

Comment: Thank you, this works! Could you explain why this is necessary?

Comment: It turns out that initializing `app.logger` before configuring is necessary because initializing `app.logger` will wipe out previously added handlers. More details in this github issue: https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/641

Answer (score 1):

Change [`logging`](https://github.com/kingheaven/ScriptFan.com/blob/5f0ee791da9d77e67ab8326c964e7c5de5aa89e3/website/scriptfan/__init__.py#L22) on line 22 to [`app.logger`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.logger) - that will configure the logger for your current Flask app.  Alternately, you can use the logging module's [`getLogger`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger) function and use [`app.logger_name`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.logger_name) to pull the correct logger.

Comment: It was hard for me to understand this since the source code link is dead.  Then I realized all you have to do is: Initialize the Flask logger first then load the logging.config().

Comment: @the_maplebar Can u post a snippet